# BOT framework - state management using Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, botframework, state-management

I have enabled the logging and state mgmt in my BOT framework using Cosmos DB as given in the below link

[Manage State using Cosmos DB](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/18/saving-state-azure-extensions/)

I added the below code in my Global.ascx as well

```
rotected void Application_Start()
{
    Conversation.UpdateContainer(
        builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
            // Bot Storage: register state storage for your bot
            var uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDBUri"]);
            var key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDBKey"];
            var store = new DocumentDbBotDataStore(uri, key);
            builder.Register(c => store)
                .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                .AsSelf()
                .SingleInstance();
        });

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

Azure document DB:

```
{
"id": "emulator:private52mgl3acgcke:default-user",
"botId": "lg3443gthi57gd",
"channelId": "emulator",
"conversationId": "52mgl3acgcke",
"userId": "default-user",
"data": {
    "ResumptionContext": {
        "locale": "en-US",
        "isTrustedServiceUrl": false
    },
    "DialogState": "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 "
},
"_rid": "JnhaAKnGzgEJAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/JnhaAA==/colls/JnhaAKnGzgE=/docs/JnhaAKnGzgEJAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00002f19-0000-0000-0000-5a56565655000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1523330900
```

}

```
  using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
            {
                var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();
                var key = new AddressKey()
                {
                    BotId = message.Recipient.Id,
                    ChannelId = message.ChannelId,
                    UserId = message.From.Id,
                    ConversationId = message.Conversation.Id,
                    ServiceUrl = message.ServiceUrl
                };
                var userData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotConversationData, CancellationToken.None);

                userData.SetProperty("userId", UserID);

                userData.SetProperty("DOB", DOB);

                BotData botdata = new BotData();


                await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
```

Now, I want to add custom user data in my state (Ex, name, email and DOB) for the user and utilize it for the complete conversation - 
I am unable to find any best way to handle it.

(context.UserData.SetValue - works, but I hope its state client and not updating it in cosmos DB)

```
context.UserData.SetValue("username", "John Smith");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "(context.UserData.SetValue - works, but I hope its state client and not updating it in cosmos DB)"? It is using CosmosDB

Comment: I have edited the question with sample code. I want to save custom user data in cosmos and retrieve it wherever i needed. . But its not getting saved as part of the data attribute in the cosmos. If I use context.UserData.SetValue - I am able to retrieve it. But its not getting saved in the cosmos though.

Comment: `its not getting saved as part of the data attribute in the cosmos` Hi @user3527063, the code work for me, user data **userId**,**DOB** and **username** are saved part of the data attribute in the cosmos, here is [test result screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMmwT.png).

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing. can you share the sample code how you implemented it. Both Save and retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unrelated but you can actually change the `var key` section of your code to just be `var key = Address.FromActivity(message);`

Using the code below i get the result in the screen shot there are a few differences one of them being I am not using this line from your code `BotData botdata = new BotData();` and I have also added this line `await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);`  I have the exact same code as you in the `global.asax`

```
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {

            var message = activity as IMessageActivity;
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
            {
                var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();
                var key = Address.FromActivity(message);

                ConversationReference r = new ConversationReference();
                var userData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, CancellationToken.None);

                userData.SetProperty("userId", "123");

                userData.SetProperty("DOB", "some date");

                await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
                await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());

        }
```

I got this result in my cosmosDB
[image]

Hope this helps you

**EDIT 4/12/2018**

To address your follow up questions.  To make it so one this code has already  ran you would just need to check if the value exists on the key modify the snippet I gave you like this:

```
if (userData.GetProperty<string>("userId") == null)
{    
    userData.SetProperty("userId", "123");
    userData.SetProperty("DOB", "some date");
    await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
    await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Since you do not have access to the context object the rest of the code will need to run for you to check the state every time.

To answer your other question about the user closing and reopening the window, it should be saved to your cosmosDB and it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks!. It worked for me as well. I got another question. Everytime when the user type something, it is going through this process. I want to set this up only once and retrieve it in my dialogs

Comment: Also, I am planning to apply this logic for Cortana and directline channels. will this be valid only for that conversation, if the user closes the window and opens it again, will everything start freshly.

Comment: I will add on to my answer to address your follow up questions.  If this works for you please accept and upvote the answer :)